# Adding images from array, content not refreshed until loop finishes

Tags: javascript, html, image, for-loop, base64

I have some code that loops through an array of base 64 images, creates a new element for each image and appends it to the div.

```
for(var i = 0; i<500; i++){
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + base64Data;
    image.alt = fileName;
    chapter.appendChild(image);
}
```

My problem is that the images are not being displayed until after the entire array is done. I need some help to make sure that each image is displayed after being appended to the div. This way if the array is of a large length, I can still display the initial images while the rest are being processed.

Thanks

Comment: Edit your question with more information about the code. What is the chapter? What is the value of the base64Data?

Answer (score 0):

Try using setTimeout:

```
var container, arr, counter, insertImages;

arr = ['xyz', 'abc'];
counter = 0;
container = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

insertImages = function () {
    var src, image;

    // Get the next src, create & inject the element
    src = arr[counter];
    image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = src;
    container.appendChild(image);

    // Increment the counter and repeat (if necessary)
    counter++;
    if ( counter < arr.length ) setTimeout(insertImages, 50);
};

// Kick it off
insertImages();
```

You might be able to reduce the timeout delay -- see what works